# Cant access remote oracle database from container

Tags: docker, containers, oracleclient

I have oracle client installed container that was downloaded from docker hub and trying to connect remote oracle database from this container but getting connect time out

> ERROR:
>   ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Using below sqlplus command to connect.

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin/sqlplus u/p@<hostname>:1521/<SID>
```

Comment: Have you firewall installed in any or both machines?

Comment: Could you please share more details? Like the command you use to run your Docker container, or the docker-compose if you use one. We need more details in order to help you.

Comment: @Carlos, yes firewall installed.

Comment: @Mornor, here is the docker command:

Comment: And have you checked that neede ports are opened. When this (timeouts) has happened to me it has been related with hostname or with needed ports that are closed. Please check incoming and outgoing ports opened in your firewall.

Comment: sudo docker run --add-host=<hostname>:ip -it <container> /bin/bash

Comment: @Carlos, checking and update you soon.

Comment: @Carlos, am able to connect now. Thanks.

Comment: So it was related with firewall?

Comment: If this was firewall related could you please self-answer the quetion or accept an answer from @Carlos for future readers?

Comment: @Carlos, It was related to firewall.

Comment: @MohammedNiaz could you accept the answer I just copied from the comments? That would be useful for another people in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that needed ports are opened. When this (timeouts) has happened to me it has been related with hostname or with needed ports that are closed. Please check incoming and outgoing ports opened in your firewall